# Enable Drivers on Lubuntu?

Tags: drivers, lubuntu

I installed the B43 Legacy drivers under the command-line using:

```
apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer
```

How do I enable the driver in Lubuntu? Ubuntu has **System** -> **Administration** -> **Hardware/Additional Drivers**. Where is the Lubuntu equivalent of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lubuntu has *LXDE menu* > ***Preferences*** > ***Additional Drivers***.

With that said, when you install a driver from the command-line with `apt-get`, it is most often automatically enabled.

Answer (score 4):

In Quantal, it is now in Preferences > Software Sources > Additional Drivers.

Answer (score 2):

And now it's LXDE Menu -> Preference -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers Tab

Comment: Also : you have to select the correct repos yourself in the "other software" tab

Answer (score -1):

LXLE Menu -> Control Menu -> Hardware -> Driver Manager