# Lubuntu 12.10 64-bit: programs won't run

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, segmentation-fault

I hope, I can get an answer, I didn't find any related topic, so I decided to make a new one...  So I tried to install several applications like Neverball or  SuperTux and they do install, but in fact i always get a segmentation fault, when i try to run these programs...   So is there a way to fix this.

I tried a few things...  Whether I installed it with apt-get install or  by using the Software center, it installs, but it doesn't run, neither using the command line nor clicking on the corresponding icons.

This problem doesn't for instance apply to OpenOffice, it seems especially games won't run...

Here for instance the output for `supertuxkart`:

```
Irrlicht Engine version 1.7.3
Linux 3.5.0-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 11 18:51:59 UTC 2012 x86_64
[FileManager] Data files will be fetched from: '/usr/share/games/supertuxkart'
[FileManager] Addons files will be stored in '/home/username/.local/share/supertuxkart/addons'.
[translate] Env var LANGUAGE = 'de_DE.UTF-8'
[translate] Env var LANGUAGE = 'de_DE.UTF-8', which corresponds to 'German (Germany)'
Adding language fallback de
[IrrDriver] Trying OpenGL rendering.
Speicherzugriffsfehler (segmentation fault)
```

The output for `sudo lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Caicos [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]
```

note that purging fglrx and reinstalling the proper versions of libGL and libglx will not solve the problem at all...

Comment: Please provide some more information. How did you install them? (`apt-get`? Synaptic? Ubuntu Software Center?) How are you trying to run them? (command line? menu item?)

Comment: yes, i tried all of those ways...

Comment: Were there any errors when you installed? What was the output of apt-get? Exactly what error is being thrown? The problem is that there are **many, many different things** that could be causing it. Basically, try to give us all of the information that seems relevant, and no more.

Comment: ok,  i put now the output of one of the programs indicated...  in the installation process everything went okay...

Comment: It looks to be failing when trying to render OpenGL. I don't know how well the default drivers work. Have you switched your video driver? If not, you may want to.

Comment: mmmh... seems reasonable, i had this problem since i installed the system... I use a sony vaio series type with Radeon graphics, how can I switch my video driver?

Comment: I posted a potential answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the proprietary ATI drivers for your video card (called `fglrx`). You can find a [fairly comprehensive how-to guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI) on this. As the guide itself says, however, the easiest way may be to use the **Hardware Drivers** manager. I'm not sure if this is accurate, but according to [an earlier answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197110/enable-drivers-on-lubuntu), the drivers manager can be found in Lubuntu under `Preferences > Software Sources > Additional Drivers` (as of Quaztal).

Comment: This seems to be even more messed up then I thought, this probably will work for most of the others with the same problem, but for me, it kind of won't. I can install the fglrx package, but when i go for fglrxinfo I receive yet again a `segmentation fault`

Comment: @Matthias: [Someone else](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1931696) seems to have had this problem, but they didn't have a Radeon card. What's the output of `sudo lspci | grep VGA`?

Comment: i added the output to my question...  unfortunately, the solution described in the link won't work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this can help you, but I noticed that the `xorg.conf` file is empty...

Comment: @Matthias: That's [not unheard of](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1799824); nowadays the X server will try to auto-detect anything it can, so the `xorg.conf` file is only necessary when you need to override something. Question: before you switched to `fglrx`, was your system running on the Open-Source driver?

Comment: Yes,  i just noticed something, when I use the live cd, the programs work correctly... Problem started probably to occur when I tried to install one of the additional driverss over the hardware assisent, which installation failed, so I didn't bother anymore...  This was  at the very beginnning of the installation...

Comment: @Matthias: If you don't have much configuration to lose, then a reinstall may be the simplest option (although it's not my favorite). Barring that, what happens when you try to run the commands with `sudo`? e.g. `sudo supertuxkart`. Others have experienced [fglrx seg faulting with non-root users](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=846016).

Comment: this is the solution I used...  It's not one of my favourites either, but I learned a lesson, don't install anything, if not necessary ^^  mmmh... how should I now deal with this question should it be closed or marked solved? It's not really solved in my opinion, but it's not anymore an important issue either.